# Which database for my specific use case

Tags: database, database-design

My head is exploding from reading about databases. I understand that which one you pick depends on the specific use case.
 So here is mine:

- I have a webapp. A game.
- It's level based, you can only go forward not back. But you can continue off of each level played. E.g. You finish Level2 and then play Level3. Then you start Level3 again and save it as Level3b. You can now continue off of Level3 and Level3b.
- Only ONE level can be played at any time.
- Three data arrays are stored on the server: 'progress', 'choices' and 'vars'
- They are modified while you play the level and then put in cold storage for when you might want to start off of them.

The currenty MySQL setup is this:

- A table 'saves' holds the metadata for each savegame, importantly the saveID and the userID it belongs to.
- Each of the data arrays has a corresponding table.
- If the player makes a choice, the insert looks like this:

  ```
  INSERT INTO choices VALUES saveid=:saveid, choice=:choice
  ```
- Thus the array can be reconstructed by doing a

  ```
  SELECT * FROM choices WHERE saveid=:saveid
  ```
- When the level is finished, the data arrays are put in cold storage by serializing them and storing them in the 'saves' table, which has 3 columns dedicated to this.
- Their values are cleared from the three other tables.
- If the player starts Level4 off of Level3b, the serialized arrays are fetched from the 'saves' table, unserialized and put back in their respective tables, albeit with the new saveID of Level4.

I hope this is somewhat understandable.
I reckon that:

- There will be many more writes than reads
- I don't need consistency, if I understand that correctly, since players can only ever manipulate their own data
- I don't think I'll be doing (m)any JOINS, since each table needs to be read individually to populate its respective data array
- So I don't think I'll be needing much in the way of a relational DB
- It should be really light load for the DB most of the way, since the inserts are small
- Datastorage must be reliable! I don't think players would stick with us if we start losing their savegames regularly. Though I think Redis' flush to disk every second would suffice, since we're not dealing with mission critical stuff here. If the game forgets the last action or two of the player it's not bad, just don't forget a whole savegame.

Can you advice me on a DB for my use case?
I've started on MySQL, now I've read about CouchDB, MongoDB, Riak, Cassandra. I think Redis is out of the picture, since that one seems to degrade badly once the dataset outgrows your RAM. But I'm open to everything.
I'm also open to people saying: stick with MySQL or goto PostgreSQL.

And I will also accept criticism about the way I've setup the storage. If you say: choose Cassandra and store it like this, I will listen.

This is a sanity check, since now is the last time I'll be able to change the DB before the game goes live and the last thing I want to do is having to swap out the DB in 3 months because it scaled badly.

Oh yeah, App is written in Javascript, communication with server is through PHP.

Comment: These arrays that you mentioned: do you ever need to access their individual elements, or you always store (and read) them as an indivisible unit at the database level?

Comment: Read is always as an indisible unit at the database level. Write is one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need to worry too much about the database - unless you are SURE you are going to have a massive userbase from day one (web apps generally dont get famous overnight).

You'd be far better off continuing with what you know (MySQL) but keep all database commands in a separate wrapper class (which you should be doing anyway).
If you do this, converting to another database is not that hard as long as you use standard SQL and dont do anything specific to that database.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Other than sheer performance, I'm also interested whether a NoSQL db like CouchDB or MongoDB is more "natural" for my highly non-relational case. I mean, I figure I'll be almost exclusively be doing Primary Key lookups.

Comment: I am not a NoSQL expert, so am happy to be corrected, but it looks like your data could be similar to normal bank transactions. You have a user table (customer) and they make choices in the game (bank transactions) and the results are aggregated to save games (accounts). Having said that, if you have no pending deadline (you say you have 3 months to release?), and want to try NoSQL as a personal learning exercise, then spend a couple of days/weeks(?) and try it out - see how it compares with some dummy data.